# RSpec: Expect to change multiple

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, matcher

I want to check for many changes in a model when submitting a form in a feature spec. For example, I want to make sure that the user name was changed from X to Y, and that the encrypted password was changed by any value.

I know there are some questions about that already, but I didn't find a fitting answer for me. The most accurate answer seems like the `ChangeMultiple` matcher by Michael Johnston here: [Is it possible for RSpec to expect change in two tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616631/is-it-possible-for-rspec-to-expect-change-in-two-tables). Its downside is that one only check for explicit changes from known values to known values.

I created some pseudo code on how I think a better matcher could look like:

```
expect {
  click_button 'Save'
}.to change_multiple { @user.reload }.with_expectations(
  name:               {from: 'donald', to: 'gustav'},
  updated_at:         {by: 4},
  great_field:        {by_at_leaset: 23},
  encrypted_password: true,  # Must change
  created_at:         false, # Must not change
  some_other_field:   nil    # Doesn't matter, but want to denote here that this field exists
)
```

I have also created the basic skeleton of the `ChangeMultiple` matcher like this:

```
module RSpec
  module Matchers
    def change_multiple(receiver=nil, message=nil, &block)
      BuiltIn::ChangeMultiple.new(receiver, message, &block)
    end

    module BuiltIn
      class ChangeMultiple < Change
        def with_expectations(expectations)
          # What to do here? How do I add the expectations passed as argument?
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But now I'm already getting this error:

```
 Failure/Error: expect {
   You must pass an argument rather than a block to use the provided matcher (nil), or the matcher must implement `supports_block_expectations?`.
 # ./spec/features/user/registration/edit_spec.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@base/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
 # /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@base/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
```

Any help in creating this custom matcher is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 284, accepted):

In RSpec 3 you can setup multiple conditions at once (so the single expectation rule is not broken). It would look sth like:

```
expect {
  click_button 'Save'
  @user.reload
}.to change { @user.name }.from('donald').to('gustav')
 .and change { @user.updated_at }.by(4)
 .and change { @user.great_field }.by_at_least(23}
 .and change { @user.encrypted_password }
```

It is not a complete solution though - as far as my research went there is no easy way to do `and_not` yet. I am also unsure about your last check (if it doesn't matter, why test it?). Naturally you should be able to wrap it within your [custom matcher](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-4/docs/custom-matchers/define-matcher).

Comment: if you want to expect that multiple things are *not* changed, simply use `.and change { @something }.by(0)`

Comment: Can you add a second example with all the parenthesis ? I's hard to understand which methods are chained

Comment: [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50649531/539149) works for Ruby 2 and seems to work with `.should_not` for anyone who needs it

Answer (score 56):

If you want to test that multiple records were not changed, you can invert a matcher using `RSpec::Matchers.define_negated_matcher`. So, add

```
RSpec::Matchers.define_negated_matcher :not_change, :change
```

to the top of your file (or to your `rails_helper.rb`) and then you can chain using `and`:

```
expect{described_class.reorder}.to not_change{ruleset.reload.position}.
    and not_change{simple_ruleset.reload.position}
```

Answer (score 4):

[BroiSatse's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29389223/539149) is the best, but if you are using RSpec 2 (or have more complex matchers like `.should_not`), this method also works:

```
lambda {
  lambda {
    lambda {
      lambda {
        click_button 'Save'
        @user.reload
      }.should change {@user.name}.from('donald').to('gustav')
    }.should change {@user.updated_at}.by(4)
  }.should change {@user.great_field}.by_at_least(23)
}.should change {@user.encrypted_password}
```

Comment: Ah, nice idea! You could probably build a wrapper to make it a bit easier to read!

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is not 100% correct since the **full** compound matcher support for `change {}` has been added in **RSpec version 3.1.0**. If you try to run the code given in accepted answer with the RSpec version 3.0, you would get an error.

In order to use compound matchers with `change {}`, there are two ways;

- First one is, you have to have at least **RSpec version 3.1.0**.
- Second one is, you have to add `def supports_block_expectations?; true; end` into the `RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::Compound` class, either by monkey patching it or directly editing the local copy of the gem. **An important note:** this way is not completely equivalent to the first one, the `expect {}` block runs multiple times in this way!

The pull request which added the full support of compound matchers functionality can be found [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/pull/567).